# Error while running espresso test: No static field NO_OP_CONTROLLED_LOOPER of type

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso, ui-testing

I got this error while running my test:

```
**No static field NO_OP_CONTROLLED_LOOPER of type**
```

Even when the test is empty with just check() function like this:

```
check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

I searched but I could not find anything about it, so after I solved my problem I decided to share here for others.
I was using these two versions:

```
// Espresso
def androidx_test_espresso = "3.2.0"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$androidx_test_espresso"

// androidx.test
def androidx_test = "1.2.0"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:runner:$androidx_test"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:core:$androidx_test"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit-ktx:$androidx_test"
```

I could overcome this problem by changing the versions to:

```
def androidx_test_espresso = "3.1.0"
def androidx_test = "1.1.0"
```

Maybe the versions above are not matched.

I hope this topic help you guys :)